# RSpec in Non-Rails Project is Looking for rails_helper -- Why?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm trying to do the "hello rspec" example from "The RSpec Book" and rspec complains it can't find "rails_helper". It doesn't complain in directories containg rails apps with rspec installed in the app-specific gemset. Rails is not installed in either of the gemsets in the rvm GEM_PATH for hello.

I set up the hello directory with: rspec --init.

I'm puzzled because this is not a Ruby On Rails project. I can't figure out where rspec is being told to require rails_helper. I'd appreciate any suggestions. Thanks!

**Leigh

```
  Mingus:hello $ rspec
    /Users/leigh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- rails_helper (LoadError)
        from /Users/leigh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /Users/leigh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rspec-hello/gems/rspec-core-3.3.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1283:in `block in requires='
        from /Users/leigh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rspec-hello/gems/rspec-core-3.3.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1283:in `each'
        from /Users/leigh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rspec-hello/gems/rspec-core-3.3.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1283:in `requires='
        from /Users/leigh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rspec-hello/gems/rspec-core-3.3.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:109:in `block in process_options_into'
        from /Users/leigh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rspec-hello/gems/rspec-core-3.3.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:108:in `each'
        from /Users/leigh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rspec-hello/gems/rspec-core-3.3.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:108:in `process_options_into'
        from /Users/leigh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rspec-hello/gems/rspec-core-3.3.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:21:in `configure'
        from /Users/leigh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rspec-hello/gems/rspec-core-3.3.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:101:in `setup'
        from /Users/leigh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rspec-hello/gems/rspec-core-3.3.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:88:in `run'
        from /Users/leigh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rspec-hello/gems/rspec-core-3.3.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:73:in `run'
        from /Users/leigh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rspec-hello/gems/rspec-core-3.3.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:41:in `invoke'
        from /Users/leigh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rspec-hello/gems/rspec-core-3.3.1/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/leigh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rspec-hello/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
        from /Users/leigh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rspec-hello/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
        from /Users/leigh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rspec-hello/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
        from /Users/leigh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rspec-hello/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Here are the path vars from /Users/leigh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rspec-hello/gems/rspec-core-3.3.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1283:in `block in requires='

```
  # @private
  def requires=(paths)
    directories = ['lib', default_path].select { |p| File.directory? p }
    RSpec::Core::RubyProject.add_to_load_path(*directories)
    STDERR.puts "paths  ------>>   #{paths}"
    STDERR.puts "default_path  ------>>   #{default_path}"
    STDERR.puts "$LOAD_PATH  ------>>   #{$LOAD_PATH}"
    paths.each { |path| require path }
    @requires += paths
  end

  paths  ------>>   ["spec_helper", "rails_helper", "spec_helper"]
  default_path  ------>>   spec
  $LOAD_PATH:
  /Users/leigh/Programming/wapp_dev/hello/spec
  /Users/leigh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib
  /Users/leigh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/executable-hooks-1.3.2
  /Users/leigh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/bundler-unload-1.0.2/lib
  /Users/leigh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.4/lib
  /Users/leigh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/bundler-1.10.3/lib
  /Users/leigh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rspec-hello/gems/rspec-support-3.3.0/lib
  /Users/leigh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rspec-hello/gems/rspec-core-3.3.1/lib
  /Users/leigh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0
  /Users/leigh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-darwin14
  /Users/leigh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby
  /Users/leigh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.2.0
  /Users/leigh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-darwin14
  /Users/leigh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
  /Users/leigh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0
  /Users/leigh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-darwin14
```

```
~/.rspec:
    --color
    --format documentation
    --require spec_helper
    #--require rails_helper
```

```
hello/.rspec:
    --color
    --require spec_helper
```

```
hello/greeter_spec.rb:
  describe "RSpec Greeter" do
    it "should say 'Hello RSpec!' when it receives the greet() message" do
      greeter = RSpecGreeter.new
      greeting = greeter.greet
      greeting.should == "Hello RSpec!"
    end
  end
```

Comment: Must be somewhere in your environment. Start picking through your dot files and ENV vars looking for the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSpec has [several locations](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-3/docs/configuration/read-command-line-configuration-options-from-files) it aggregates the options from (listed in lowest to highest precedence):

- `~/.rspec`
- `.rspec`
- `.rspec-local`
- command line switches
- `SPEC_OPTS` environment variable

I would double check all of those. It may seem silly but be sure your `~/.rspec` file has been saved; done this one to myself too many times. Also, stop any pre-loaders such as spring, guard, and spork. I would also check to make sure you didn't accidentally alias `rspec` with something else (i.e. check `which rspec` and `alias | grep rspec`).

If all that fails, you can peek into RSpec's internals (this is specific to your current version, but may work for others). Add the following to a file in your project for example: `trace_opts.rb`

```
require 'rspec/core'
module TraceOpts
  def self.trace_options(opt)
    name = opt.to_s.split('_').map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
    define_method(opt) do |*args, &block|
      super(*args, &block) { |opts| puts "#{name}: #{opts}" }
    end
  end

  def self.trace_file(opt)
    name = opt.to_s.split('_').map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
    define_method(opt) do |*args, &block|
      super(*args, &block).tap { |opts|
        opts = opts ? File.expand_path(opts) : "No File Specified"
        puts "#{name}: #{opts}"
      }
    end
  end

  trace_options :env_options
  trace_options :command_line_options
  trace_options :custom_options
  trace_options :local_options
  trace_options :project_options
  trace_options :global_options

  trace_file :custom_options_file
  trace_file :project_options_file
  trace_file :local_options_file
  trace_file :global_options_file
end
RSpec::Core::ConfigurationOptions.prepend(TraceOpts)
RSpec::Core::Runner.invoke
```

Then run it with `ruby trace_opts.rb` and it should show you where things are being loaded from.

**EDIT:** The option files that RSpec reads are parsed as [ERB](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html) files. They are then fed through [`OptionParser`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html). Setting can be ignored at the ERB parsing level by using the ERB comment:

```
<%# --require rails_helper %>
```

When the line is commented out with plain Ruby `#` it is provided to the option parser. Depending where in the order this occurs can have an affect on what the option parser does. In the few permutations I tried the commented option was included as part of the `files_or_directories_to_run`. The RSpec configuration code removes that particular option before proceeding.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Aaron. I've done the "forgot to save" thing at least twice! But in this case I did save. Also SPEC_OPTS is not set and there are no command line switches, just the bare 'rspec' command. Rspec is in the correct gemset and it's not aliased.

Comment: Added a short script to help trace things down.

Answer (score 0):

I now know that the # mark is NOT a comment indicator in the .rspec file!

It showed that ~/.rspec was including rails_helper when I thought the # made it invisible. Removing "#--require rails_helper" did the trick!

Thanks for the script, Aaron, and for taking the time to help out!

**Leigh